# IndexError when iterating a list and deleting item from a DIFFERENT list

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing

Say I want to remove the number 4 from `myList`, I iterate through the list and if its equal to 4, I delete the item from a `tempList` which is not being iterated through. For some reason this still causes an IndexError even though it isn't iterating the same list.

```
myList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
tempList = myList

# Goes through each item and if it is 4, then it deletes it from the tempList
for i in range(9):
    if myList[i] == 4:
        del tempList[i]
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ***, line 5, in <module>
    if myList[i] == 4:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

My only idea is that somehow by deleting an item in `tempList`, it also does so in `myList` as well - somehow they are linked. If so, how do I make `tempList` not 'linked' to `myList` .

Comment: `tempList` and `myList` are two names for a single object.  Python never automatically copies anything, you have to explicitly request that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello you can create a real copy of `myList` and change the looping range ;) :

```py
myList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
tempList = myList.copy()

# Goes through each item and if it is 4, then it deletes it from the tempList
for i in range(len(myList)):
    if myList[i] == 4:
        del tempList[i]
```

Comment: Thanks that works for me. Do you know why I have to use .copy() and not just use my original method?

Comment: @hjw In your method, you reference the variable `tempList ` towards `myList ` meaning that they are both using the same value. Instead, you have a create a copy of the value itself!